# What to do about [macros]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138044/should-the-macros-tag-be-removed-from-vba-questions) was last asked about 2 years ago and it is still an issue. The wiki's both seem to have been updated, but the vast majority of people abusing this tag are new users (whom I can safely assume are not reading the tag wikis).

Out of 9,439 [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros)questions:

- 2938 are also tagged with [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba)
- 3190 have [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) (likely a lot of overlap)

That's a lot of junk, and I only checked on MS Office related tags. I'm sure other languages are abusing this tag as well. What do we do? Even if we *just* cleaned up the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) related questions, that's still several thousand questions to deal with and *then* the tag just continues to be abused by new users who think (thanks to Microsoft) that [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) = [macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macro).

I've been replacing macros with vba in new questions as I see them, but that's a drop in the bucket and does little to stem the tide.

How do we clean this up?

I would really like input from the other sub-communities affected by this. I only know how this is affecting the vba portion of the community.

Edit:  There are now (6/11/18) 6874 [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) questions

- [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros)+[excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) no [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) - [201 Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros+excel+-vba)
- [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros)+[vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) no [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) - [236 Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros+-excel+vba)
- [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros)+[vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba)+[excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) - [919 Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros+excel+vba)

[All [macros] + ([excel] or [vba]) questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros+excel+OR+vba+macros)

**At least <s>5560</s> <s>447</s> 1356 questions improperly tagged with [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros)**

---

- [ms-word + macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word+macros?sort=newest&pageSize=50): 121 questions

Be careful with Access questions. There ***are*** things called "Macros" in access that are not VBA. I don't know whether or not it's appropriate to leave the tag on those questions.

- [ms-access + macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access+macros): 136 questions
- [access-vba + macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba+macros): 34 questions

Comment: The tag wiki itself states "Similarly, questions relating to other macro programming languages should not use this tag", although I think that's pretty bias.

Comment: The tag mentions what a macro is not, but it doesn't actually say what a macro *is*.  Without a clear use case for what questions *should* use this tag, and how this tag helps them, it seems like this is a tag that just doesn't add any value at all.

Comment: @Servy, there is a link to a Wikipedia article (that's actually kind of interesting), but that's not practical nor in the spirit of SO.

Comment: @ckuhn203 Once again, the tag does not inform me, as a reader of it, what types of questions *should* use this tag.  That is the tag wiki's sole purpose, and it fails to accomplish it.

Comment: @Servy No argument from me. If [tag:Macros] stays, it needs a proper wiki.

Comment: [macro] is an essential tag with relevance for the C and C++ languages. The tag wiki is wrong.

Comment: Any thoughts on how we could keep it from being abused if we cleaned up the vba posts? @codygray

Comment: @Servy  I added the excerpt from the tag wiki into the actual wiki. That helps a little bit with the "What *is* it?" issue.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't know what the wiki should read. If you think it is wrong, please update it, as I don't know what it *should* be.

Comment: "Macros" is so generic a term, meaning so totally different thing in different contexts (Lisp, C/C++, m4, Excel...), that it sounds like a meta tag. Aren't those frowned upon?

Comment: [Haxe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros+haxe) has [macros](http://haxe.org/manual/macro.html) too. Just saying ... ;-)

Comment: Sure @pnuts I can do that soon. I've been actively working on [excel]. That one was just under 4k last time I checked, but I'll get some updated numbers soon. Thank you for the interest and support.

Comment: I am interested/willing to help knock out the [excel] related ones.  I just reached 2000 so I should be able to work quickly through them.  Which tags are we trying to add if they are VBA related?  Both [vba] and [excel-vba] or just one of those?  I know there's been some controversy there.

Comment: I fall on the both side of that argument @Byron, but use your best judgement. I gave up on this endeavor some time ago.

Comment: Thanks, any particular reason you gave up on it?

Comment: Yeah. There wasn't much support for cleaning it up, so I wasn't getting much help. *And* I couldn't handle staring at ***really*** bad questions for that length of time @Byron

Comment: I tried to remove the tags on some recent questions. At least those I was sure of could do without this [macros] tag. However it is a pain because all my edits require review. And there are a lot of people voting NO, since they don't read my comment with my edit, just state that I don't make any changes. Luckily none of the edits has completely been voted down.

Comment: Also it is now down to around 1400 questions making the same sum as TS did.

Comment: I have been retagging some questions today. Only a few at a time as not to overflow the review system. However I also see a lot of questions containing `Macros` and other MS-Office related terms such as word, powerpoint and outlook. Perhaps TS can add some numbers about those as well. Perhaps we might be doing the wrong thing here seeing that I don't find many questions that are correctly tagged with `Macros`

Comment: Also some people are voting reject, and then in turn edit the question them selves. How mature of an action for that 2 points of rep.

Comment: @Luuklag are you *only* changing the tag? You should be cleaning up the questions as much as possible. Even though the bar for edits is "officially" lower than it used to be, many of the people in the queues are stuck in an old mindset.

Comment: Most questions don't even contain the word macros, or use it in such a way that there is no real good alternative. If possible I edit out Macros all together, at least in the title.

Comment: I encountered an error today trying to edit this post; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31814567/excel-label-formatting-uses-cell-formatting The content is okay, seeing that is already answered. The only thing that needs editing is the removal of the macros tag, however I need to edit at least 6 characters in the main body...

Comment: I did that one just now @Luuklag

Comment: `macros + vba + excel` is 100 questions down from last week right now.

Comment: @pnuts wow! Someone's been busy!

Comment: Nice job @pnuts. I also did a lot of them, but don't have the time anymore since recently. I saw only `[macros] + [vba] NO excel` remained. Also for me editing was difficult as all had to be approved by review, that's why I only could do 6 at a time, as not to flood the review system.

Comment: What's left is significantly smaller and easier to deal with.

Comment: Also 57 questions with `[powerpoint]` and `[macros]`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint+macros most of which are also tagged with `[vba]`

Comment: @pnuts I'll try to dedicate some time to it. If anyone removes the tag from ***new*** questions, please drop a link back to this meta so we can educate users to stop using it.

Comment: I fixed the counts @pnuts. I'm not sure what I was counting there....

Comment: I've spent my whole career here on SO (post-2k rep anyway) retagging [tag:macros][tag:sas] to [tag:sas-macros].  Sigh.

Comment: You're not alone @Joe. You're not alone.

Comment: @Luuklag By the way, people who can reject suggested edits are over 2k reputation, and therefore don't gain any rep from edits they make themselves. +2 rep per edit stops after 1,000 reputation

Comment: @Luuklag, have you read the bottom of [this post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/213671) It's great that you are helping, but keep note of the amount of strain you are putting on the suggested edit queue.

Comment: @gunr2171 that's what the queue is there for. That's like saying "No. Don't help me. Let me do it. Oh... no. I'm not going to do it either. Just don't fix it. Not my house."

Comment: The [macros] tag is detrimental to my sub-community and it does need to be cleaned up when it comes to vba.

Comment: @TylerH, +2k rep per edit doesn't stop after 1000 rep, as I still got them.

Comment: @gunr2171, If you read my post somewere above, you would have known that I am aware of that, but chose to ignore it. July 30, or Sept 16 for example.

Comment: @Luuklag No I meant you can gain a total of 1,000 rep from edit recommendations. AKA you can go from 1 to 1,001 rep with them, but also 500 to 1,500 as well. You stop once you've earned 1,000 rep from suggested edits or hit a total of 2,000 reputation on the site, whichever comes first.

Comment: Just thought to check up on this. There are close to 1900 questions now improperly tagged with [macros]. With the limit of 5 pending edits at a time I personally can't do much about it. Not that the limit is such a bad thing though. It makes me wonder though if there is a propper use of the [macros] tag, and if it is even used all that much, or that we just could do without.

Comment: Today I put in the updated numbers in the question again. I think it's time we come up with a more permanent solution. As these tags clearly cause a lot of confusion.

Comment: @RubberDuck So have new questions come up with macros again or were we supposed to see `excel + macros` again?

Answer (score 12):

["Macro"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_(computer_science)) can mean so many different things in programming, such as programming editor macros (which are rather different in different editors and IDEs), simple and less simple text substitution macros (such as C/C++ preprosessor macros, and macro languages like m4), VBA macros, and constructs like Lisp macros.

In other words, if you look for "[macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros)" questions, you get questions about things which essentially have nothing in common. [This old blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) uses term "dependent tags". And trying to use wiki entry to restrict meanings of a word like this doesn't work, and sounds wrong even if posters would obey.

As I understand it, tags like this are prime candidates for burnination.

Better have multiple tags, which say what macros they are about.

Comment: "Better have multiple tags" Do you have any recommendations on what new tags need to be created to replace [tag:macros]?

Comment: @KevinBrown [he mentioned earlier](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256623/what-to-do-about-macros/284041#comment144965_284025) that [tag:preprocessor] could replace macros for the non-vba use. I don' t know enough about the "other" uses of the tag to say.

Comment: @KevinBrown Well, I guess simply *vba-macros*, *cpp-macros*, *lisp-macros*, *vim-macros* and so on.

Comment: I'll burn [tag:vba-macros] faster than you can spit.

Comment: @RubberDuck I know almost nothing about them, but it seems to be a concept people talk about and more-or-less agree what it means. But what ever is the correct term for them, that should be the base for the tag.

Comment: Well..... you've got a point. It could be created and then synomized. That way people who don't know what they're talking about find the tag they're looking for in spite of themselves.

Comment: "**macro**" does not have different meanings, the issue steams with people attributing it to a platform: both in the questions that have it tagged, and in this post discussion. This is kind of ridiculous, because it's platform independent. However, it absolutely CAN describe the context of a question AND content in a question. It can stand alone as a tag.

Comment: on a separate note, I understand and disagree with the meta-tag notion and discouragment, this dependent tag "issue", as well as the impulsive decision to refactor the tagging system. If you can identify the difference between tags that describe the context/content of a Q&A, and those that attribute a meaning/value (like best-practices)... then you should facility that difference as well as what's being described.. make it a feature...

Comment: Actually, [tag:excel-macros] at least is legitimate in my book: you might have questions about using VBA script in a macro, or using the macro recorder.  VBA I guess perhaps not.

Answer (score 8):

We can't just burn the tag entirely because it does have a valid use and relevance for the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) languages. So, we're going to need to clean up [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) by hand. Which sucks. Pretty bad. But I'm willing to put some effort into cleaning this up. Hopefully some others in the community will lend a hand.

The [tag wiki was recently revised](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5012832/revisions) to call out that this tag should not be used on [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) questions.

It also makes sense to create a [vba-macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba-macros) tag to be synomized with plain old [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba). This way, people who don't understand that [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) != [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) will find the correct tag in spite of themselves. I plan on doing this as soon as I have a moment.

As for the re-tagging effort, let's start with the Excel Questions tagged with macro. Then, we can move on to the other office applications. Be sure when ***suggesting*** to make edits that address any and all issues with the question (if privileged to edit without review, just fix whatever you can,  when you can). Also, feel free to downvote/VTC bad and off topic questions. Don't bother removing the tag from negative score, no answer questions. They'll get swept up by the roomba eventually.

You can also help by removing [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) from any newly created [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) questions.

Please feel free to add useful searches here to be cleaned up and mark them off as they are completed.

- [[macros] + [excel]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros+excel) - <s>2,947 questions (down from over 4100)</s> `0` (@20151210)
- [[macros] + [excel-vba]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros+excel-vba) - <s>1780 questions</s> `0` (@20151210)
- [[macros] + [vba]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba+macros) - <s>2987 questions</s> `0` (@20151210)

(Without double-counting, ie [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros)[excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel)[vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) nil.)

Comment: Why mention C/C++? With them, [tag:macros] overlaps almost 100% with [tag:preprosessor]. Better example might be Lisp. Possibly also m4 and similar macro languages, though then "macro" part is implied.

Comment: @hyde because I don't know jack about C/C++ and [this guy insisted it was relevant](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256623/what-to-do-about-macros/284025?noredirect=1#comment31313_256623).

Comment: @hyde if you think this can be burnt wholesale, can you please post an answer saying so?

Comment: @pnuts I can't say I disagree. The tag attracts a... certain kind of user. I've been putting effort into the ones that deserve it and blitz the rest.

Comment: @pnuts I updated the counts. Starting to make a dent on the Excel questions.

Comment: Feel free to edit @pnuts. (That is much less daunting btw.)

Comment: `[macros]+[excel]` is at 0 now, and `[macros]+[vba]` is below 100 now.

Comment: @Chrismas007 for `[Macros] + [Excel]` I only see 2 posts, instead of the 172 you list....

Comment: I updated the number of posts in the Q now, such a shame to see all work being undone again. We should think of a more permanent solution.

Comment: @Luuklag yeah, like blacklisting... or blacklisting.

Comment: @Braiam, that would be a solution, but then what should we do for the legitimate uses of the tag. Last time I checked we can't blacklist only a combination of tags.

Comment: There *are* legitimate uses for this tag. Just not for VBA.

Comment: I would say that [macros] isn't a good tag by any metric. It means whatever the reader wants it to mean, and isn't immediately obvious. Now, we need a good text for Shog to put in the error message.

Answer (score 2):

I know Access has legitimate Macros, and there exists an [office-macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-macros) tag.  I think you need to either decide whether that tag will also be burninated, or be careful to **re-tag** the questions relating to Access (and possibly other applications that have macros) and not just dump them.  In other words, be careful about questions tagged as just "[macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macro)" and "[vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba)".

I agree that Excel questions can have the macro tag dumped, though.  Modules are VBA, they're not macros, and should be tagged as such.

Comment: Agreed, but we're a long way from getting around to Access.

Comment: Nope. You're right @pnuts. That tag is *gone*.

Answer (score -1):

So there are only the macros in Access that can be tagged with the macros-tag? What about the macros from Excel and Word? If I want to know how to activate a macro in Excel from Word I cannot tag it with macros? Great. Why don't you just alter the tag from macros to Access-macros? Would be easier to understand... Of course everyone who's new, will make this mistake... Not everyone's got the time to read every tag-description... But I will read everything from now on...

Comment: Don't tag either of them macros. Neither word nor excel nor access. Tag with the language instead, and maybe the program.

Comment: Ok, I think i will just add the most neccessairy tags from now on... Thank you Duplicator :)

Comment: I think this is exactly the confusion I was talking about. Excel & Word *don't have* anything called a "macro". You can call VBA code, but Access is the only one that has macros. And macros don't require any VBA code. Honestly, IMO, Access-Macro questions belong on Super User.

Comment: Wrong. There are things called macros in Excel in Word. Have you ever activated the developers-tab? There is a menu called "Macros". Macros are being scripted with vba, but these still ARE MACROS. If I really am wrong I would like a Wikipedia-like declaration of "Macro" (Wikipedia-entry for Macros: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: It's a terribly confusing term, and a hold over from when Excel and Word had *actual* macros.

Comment: What Word and Excel have can be debated. What ACCESS has that is designated "Macro" is definitely NOT VBA - it's something else entirely. Access does have MACROS and they can be executed by VBA and sometimes provide a useful alternative to writing a lot of code to accomplish a task, so I don't believe they should be banned to SuperUser as @RubberDuck suggests.