# Anonymous user(s) submitting tag-only edits referencing specific meta question in summary

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

Seen two edits today so far that mentioned [What to do about [macros]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256623/what-to-do-about-macros) in their summary and were adding various vba-ish tags, both by anonymous users. That's really baffling. Did someone forget to log in, or are they trying to work around a ban on editing, or is some random passerby simply poking deep into meta for grins?

Note that the edits look pretty reasonable as far as I can tell; I'm just puzzled by the characteristics of the suggester(s).

[First](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8007400), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8007450), [third](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8007458), [fourth](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8007546) examples. (So far I've skipped them all, in case you're wondering.)

Comment: Maybe they are testing out their bot?

Comment: @Roombatron5000: I suppose that's possible too.

Comment: @Roombatron5000: Yeah, no, [it's not a bot](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8007450).

Comment: I also found that too and notice  all the edits are same.I skipped all but rejected one thinking the suggestion as spam

Comment: @ShaifulIslam: All the same? Check links; they all look unique to me.