# Macros tag - how about we stop pissing against the wind?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) tag is problematic. If you are not already familiar with the problem, here is some reading:

- [Previous Meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256623/what-to-do-about-macros)
- [Discussion before that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138044/should-the-macros-tag-be-removed-from-vba-questions)

In short, the [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) tag description says:

> *Not for MS-OFFICE / VBA / macro languages. Use the respective tags instead.*

In reality, a lot of MS Office macro questions are being asked by new users, who just don't read tag descriptions.

The "solution" seems to be regularly going on clean-up missions, spending time deleting the macros tags on literally hundreds of questions. That is not a real solution, and it can even result in an [editing ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320746/banned-from-editing-for-cleaning-up-macros-tag).

So, my final suggestion: how about we stop "proudly pissing against the wind", and accept the fact that everyone on planet Earth calls MS Office VBA macros just that: *Macros*. And they are right: after all, that's what those are.

**I suggest we remove the first sentence from the [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) tag description, and let it be used for MS Office macros too.** And at the same time, we create a new tag, something like [Macros - Non MS Office] or [Non-VBA Macros] (open to suggestions) for users who actually want to ask about other types of macros. (By looking at the questions, these users are usually higher-rep users, who might actually know what they are doing.)

Pros:

- This fits the generally accepted terminology

  - easier navigation for new users
  - easier searches
  - maybe even better search optimization
- Not confusing (OpenOffice macros are OK, MS office macros not? That's what it says now.)
- No need for clean-up missions
- We would still have a separate [Macros - non-VBA] tag that doesn't get clogged up

The only con I can think of is "Hurr-durr my OCD and our traditional rules"

Thoughts?

Comment: Can I add a little twist to the story? Anyone who thinks that regular clean-ups are enough, please put your money where your mouth is, and go ahead and clean at least 30 misplaced macros tags! :)

Comment: I agree with your analogy of pissing against the wind, but the conclusion is just not a "conclusion", is just giving up. I suggest that we obliterate the tag, and then we stop having this problem.

Comment: Accepting reality is not giving up in my opinion. What I'm saying here is that our rule is bad, so instead of enforcing it, let's change it. Obliterating the tag seems harsh to me, the tag is needed sometimes... Maybe renaming it to [Non-VBA Macros] could be a middle ground.

Comment: That just asking for a "compromise"... and [the middle ground is not always the solution](https://xkcd.com/690/). My solution is definite and sensible. People tend to shot themself in the foot? Prevent them from doing so, not just accept that they will hurt themselves.

Comment: @Braiam :) Ok, but nobody is shooting nobody in this case. We have a bad tag: the description goes against common usage. That said, the tag itself is good, if we get the description right. Why shouldn't we have a general [Macros] tag? Sounds a bit like "We can't have it our way, then we won't have it at all." Our way is wrong in this case.

Comment: Sigh... that's why we can't have nice things. Tags are things that are supposed to be meaningful ways to get your question the right kind of attention, so it can get answered, is not an accessory without use. People using this tags are *shooting themselves in the foot* because their questions doesn't have the optimal pool of users that can help their questions getting answered, and when they do, the answerer is practically taking [stabs in the dark](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25017822), since their questions are just that bad.

Comment: [A cool search query for the ones that want to see the kind of cesspool this tag is without proper moderation](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[macros]%20-[c]%20is%3aq%20-[c-pre*]%20-[excel*]%20-[pre*]%20-[vba]%20-[java]%20-[rust]%20-[access]%20-[julia*]%20-[erlang*]%20answers%3a0)

Comment: What does "respective tags" in the excerpt mean?

Comment: @Laurel in this case, it means the Excel-VBA, PowerPoint-VBA and so on tags. Totally unintuitive.

Answer (score 1):

If we could [force users to disambiguate problematic tags manually when they try to use them](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags), this wouldn't be much of a problem; we'd just have [script-macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script-macros) and [preprocessor-macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preprocessor-macros) and make everyone who puts just "macros" choose one or the other.

Since we can't, yet, let's at least focus user education on those that are generally closer to the professional programmer ideal (and presumably **1.** fewer in number and **2.** better able to make distinctions), and switch C-ish macros over to [preprocessor-macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preprocessor-macros). ([visual-studio-macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-macros) can stick around and be added to appropriate questions; whether it should be added alongside [script-macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script-macros) on such questions is another matter. If there's room and it's not just about the specifics of VS, it might work.)

Comment: Actually we can, we can blacklist a tag and put a custom message with guidance.

Comment: That is a very good feature request. I also agree with pushing higher level users to another, better tag.

Comment: Can you add [visual-sudio-macros] to your answer? It already exists...

Comment: @Laurel: What do you mean, exactly? If anything, that's closer to "script macros" in concept, but if it's being appropriately used that doesn't require any retagging.

Comment: @NathanTuggy No, I mean add it to the list of your alternatives.