# Are [lang-macros] tags redundant?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

It seems to me that the [[scala-macros]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-macros), [[lisp-macros]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lisp-macros), and [[julia-macros]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julia-macros) tags are redundant with the combination of the respective language tag and the general [[macros]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros). Should these tags just be made synonyms of [macros], and existing questions retagged? Note the only tag above actually in common use is [scala-macros].

Comment: They are of course.  This kind of nonsense happens because everybody loves to hate [visual basic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323542/macros-tag-how-about-we-stop-pissing-against-the-wind).