# What to do about [macros] again?

Tags: discussion, tags

As some of you may recall this discussion was started 3 years ago: [What to do about [macros]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256623/what-to-do-about-macros)

At one point in time due to the effort of many users the tag was almost cleared of inccorect use. At 9/18/15 the amount of incorectly tagged questions was reduced from 5500+ to less then 500.

Unfortunately things haven't been going great since then. In the day I personally edited a lot of questions, but with my limited reputation it wasn't that productive and put some serious strain on the suggested edit queue. Today doing such thing isn't even possible anymore due to the limit on the suggested edits queue. So as much as I would like to see the [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) tag cleaned, and the questions made findable under the proper [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tag I am not going to be able to do this. (at least not by myself)

Today the extent of the damage luckily isn't as big as back then, with only 1700 questions tagged improperly: [questions tagged with macros and (excel or vba)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros+excel+OR+vba+macros). But are we as a community able to keep this tag clean? Clearly the text in the tag-wiki isn't discouraging people from "abusing" the tag, and first posters clearly aren't educated enough on what tags to use.

Another option that was suggested here: [Macros tag - how about we stop pissing against the wind?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323542/macros-tag-how-about-we-stop-pissing-against-the-wind), to just let things be, clearly didn't get much support.

A third option would be, as was suggested in the comments of the previously linked meta post to just obliterate the tag. Which I could agree with, seeing that the tag wiki has no clear definition of what the tag should be used for.

So let's vote. Who is in favour of:

1. Clearing up the existing `macros` tag (please clean a couple of questions then)
2. Just giving up
3. Obliterating the `macros` tag

Comment: @pusbsee2003 Thanks for fixing the link, overlooked it completely.