# Is the [code.org] tag meta?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is the [code.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code.org) a meta tag? There are 18 questions and the questions seem to be of mixed quality. To me the language/framework tags are more important than the scope of where the question comes from.

There also seems to be a related [app-lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/app-lab) tag.

Comment: It doesn't seem meta to @Andrew Oberhardt, that's how he finds users that need his assistance.  That 15 SO users that favored the tag is not enough to effectively moderate that tag and get rid of the junk is a well-known problem.

Comment: Hum, downvoted because I don''t even understand the Qt...: "*Is the [code.org] tag meta?*" Sorry but doesn't make any/much sense to me... :(+ Not much Info in the Body...) oops:

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a Meta tag. We recently removed the [Codility tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404309/can-we-remove-the-codility-meta-tag) for exactly the reason you state: this is the name of a platform, not a programming topic.

[app-lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/app-lab) may be on topic because it appears to be a programming environment. I'm admittedly not very familiar with it, but it seems like this falls under the category of programming tools. It does, however, need to be cleaned up, as do [many of the IDE tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355004/can-there-be-tag-warnings-for-android-studio-and-visual-studio).