# Can we remove the Codility meta tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

So, we apparently have a [codility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codility) tag now, which currently has 10 questions. This is a classic Meta tag because Codility is a testing platform, not a type of programming question. In general, the fact that it's a Codility question has little to no bearing on whether someone is likely to know the answer or not.

This is eligible for the abbreviated burnination process. Can we remove this?

Comment: I'm in favor. Currently all 10 questions tagged as such are simply about problems found *on* the Codility platform. This would be no different than tagging a post with the name of a textbook you found a CS problem in— burn it.

Comment: Are we sure about this? Is the tag itself off topic in any context? Meta tags could be useful in some instances, that's why we keep some of them around - for example the sudoku tag.

Comment: @cs95 [tag:sudoku] at least somewhat describes the content of the tag, but questions with [tag:codility] have no relation to each other whatsoever other than appearing on the same testing platform.

Comment: @cs95 [You were sure before in a similar situation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399117/we-need-to-de-leet-leetcode); what's changed? I agree that [sudoku] is an entirely different case, since that's an actual game.

Comment: @CodyGray not familiar with this tag tbh, and the 4 shog points were not laid out in this post so I was lacking a clear understanding of whether this made sense or not.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're right; this tag is not useful for categorizing questions and there is evidence that it is causing harm. I've added it to the pyre, as with [all previous coding competition tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399119).

I've gone through all the questions with the tag, closing most of them, deleting around half, and removing the tag, since it was not directly related to the topic of the question (only the context in which the question arose).

Only one question remains: [test-input.txt in codility how to pass multiple values and expected vs actual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63594997/test-input-txt-in-codility-how-to-pass-multiple-values-and-expected-vs-actual)

I'm not quite sure how to deal with that one. It seems that the tag is at least somewhat appropriate there, since the question is actually about the platform itself, rather than a specific challenge posed on the platform. But then, because of that, I'm not sure whether the question is actually on-topic. Removing that tag leaves a question that can't really be found; the other tags aren't even especially relevant or appropriate. Thoughts?

Comment: [It was deleted before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399117/we-need-to-de-leet-leetcode). Does deleting a tag not ban the tag?

Comment: @samanthaj No, it can still be created again.

Comment: that's sad, sounds very sisyphean like there isn't much point in deleting tags.

Comment: It is technically possible to blacklist a tag, but in practice it is hardly ever done. It just isn't worth the time and effort.

Comment: *Only one question remains...I'm not quite sure how to deal with that one.* The question is about how to use a feature on the Codility site itself. Is the site considered to fall into the category of "software tools commonly used by programmers"? Both jsFiddle and CodePen have tags for questions about how to use those sites and this seems similar.

Comment: I took a quick stroll across their website, and it seems there is no documentation about the test file format. At least none that is accessible without paying for an account. So, I would argue that the question can only be answered by Codility's customer support and is thus [off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/2988). Even if by any chance someone from Codility customer support and/or a paying customer of Codility's with access to the documentation were trying to answer the question, "I am getting errors" is not a sufficiently detailed problem description.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Hi, I am the poster of aforementioned question, couldn't this suggestion (just contact support) then be applied to any software. Every time 3rd party soft is used just RTFM, contact support? Or only for online tools? BTW I deleted the question, so the problem is gone.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius of course. There should be proper customer support in the case that the service they provide requires *ahem* support. This is the same for bug reporting for non-services.

Comment: FYI: the tag was created again 2 days ago