# Is there a way to clarify a commonly misused tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm around the [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) tag a lot and I feel that around half the questions tagged with it are done wrongly so.

Common cases:

- Used because the code is written in [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) (The tag excerpt already warns to not do that)
- Used together with [mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mac) instead of [visual-studio-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-mac)
- Used for questions about [visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code)

Not only hampers that the OP because it does not appear for users routinely browsing the actual tags, but it also kinda pollutes the actual tag with irrelevant questions.

Besides editing questions and correcting or removing the tags, is there anything else I/we can do? I'm imagining some kind of popup upon usage to clarify what and when to tag, [which was apparently a thing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips/274634#274634), but I have no idea if that still exists (I've never seen it personally).

Comment: A tag warning is still a thing. The main problem is that the discoverabilty of tag excerpts is low, specially for new users, and with the new design it didn't get much better. I still have hope tag guidance will improve with the upcoming Ask question wizard but the work on it has stalled from my point of view, maybe because we needed to become welcoming first.

Comment: Looks like someone else asked something similar: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355004/can-there-be-tag-warnings-for-android-studio-and-visual-studio

Comment: also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354934/what-determines-what-tags-will-get-a-popup-with-usage-guidance

Comment: There are 3 that I know of: renaming, removing and blacklisting, and the warning rene talks about. The observed effectivity is, in order, 2, 3 and 1.

Comment: I pushed pretty hard for [vscode], knowing this was going to happen.  But it is "visual studio" to everybody, so that didn't go anywhere and the synonym is the wrong way around.  Only the [vscode-something] tags remained.  Cold hard fact is that users invariably need lots of help with their question, retagging is but a small part of it.

Comment: Related: [Make tag popups display permanently while editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201587)

Comment: All compilers and IDE:s get this problem. (Look at Eclipse) The best solution is simply to re-tag such questions as they pop up. A larger problem might be the various visual-studio 20xx tags that are mostly useless. We don't make a tag called gcc-8.2 each time there's a new version of gcc, now do we? Feels like those tags are the result of MS marketing hype more than an actual need for them.

Comment: @Lundin I'd generally agree, but there are actually many differences between VS versions, specially when it comes to project templates and technologies you can/cannot use. I agree that the tag is polluted with irrelevant questions, however.

Comment: Exactly the same thing happens with the [android-studio] tag. About half of the questions are to do with general Android development and nothing to do with the IDE itself, despite the warning in the tag description.

Comment: @Dukeling, that might soon be [status-completed], under the new tag-warning system. (A [bug in the new system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315106/311398) displays it permanently, even if you remove the tag) .

Comment: The Tag field needs to be replaced with multiple controls. The separate [Tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) already has multiple ways to search, but new users will not first go to that page just to find appropriate tags before drafting their question.  A single control for choosing and listing tags looks nice and simple, but it limits usability and is generally rather inflexible how it interprets spaces and matches possible tags.

Comment: [NO MATTER HOW BOLD YOU PUT THE GUIDELINES, PEOPLE WILL STILL IGNORE THEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52370041/windows-server-license-confusion#comment91731696_52370041).

Comment: Accurately tagging questions is an issue, albeit one pretty far down the list. Just fix it where you see it, and accept that it will always be an option to ask a question about jQuery and tag it as Java; as such, it will always be happening. *sic semper erat, et sic semper erit*

Comment: @TravisJ  Well that'll solve all sorts of issues. SO developers can just post the top 3 issues and for the remaining problems... everyone just stop posting meta questions.  Oh the paradox, since posting the top issues probably isn't at the top either, so this will never happen.  Maybe since users will continue to post question on issues that are not top priority, we should probably just stop posting useless comments on why we should just accept it how it is.  Why are we all developers to start with?  Let's just leave it all as it is.

Comment: @CPerkins - No, it wont. It just happens to be the best option we have here. As for the list, hopefully you don't honestly think it is 3 items long. Perhaps you should look around more since it seems your meta experience is a little limited.