# What should we do with the [rust-macros] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently:

- [47 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-macros) tagged 
  with [rust-macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-macros)
- [233 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust+macros) tagged with [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) & [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust)

We have considered removing [rust-macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-macros) because there aren't many questions, but the tag *does* allow us to have some extra information and links in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust-macros/info). Rust macros recently became more powerful, so this is a big topic, which is likely to attract more questions in the future.

There are two main kinds of macro in Rust; procedural and "by-example". The latter is less powerful, but has its own unique syntax, which can be something of a learning curve for newcomers. The former doesn't have special syntax, but involves traversing an AST, which also can be a difficult concept for newcomers to the topic.

Either way, a macro in Rust is very different to a macro in C/C++ or any of the other languages that dominate the tag (including plenty of [mis-tagged Excel & VBA questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256623/what-to-do-about-macros)).

A suggestion from the Rust chat room is retire [rust-macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-macros) and to re-tag all [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) macro-related questions with two new tags: [proc-macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proc-macro) and [macro-by-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macro-by-example), which will help to group questions which are likely to have  similar root problems or are answerable by people with more specific expertise.

Comment: *with two new tags* — with *one or both of* two new tags, right?

Comment: Would we also remove [tag:macros] at the same time?

Comment: @Shepmaster I think we would remove [tag:macros] at the same time.

Comment: @Shepmaster That's a good point. There might be questions where the answer is to use the _other_ macro type, or where both types are relevant.

Comment: The [tag:macros] tag is wildly overused over at [tag:excel] & [tag:vba] - it's a constant clean up process there.

Answer (score 13):

As macros in Rust have a specific syntax, like most other languages, I think [rust-macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-macros) makes sense.

Adding [proc-macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proc-macro) is a good idea but I think we should keep `rust` in front of stuff related to Rust, so [rust-proc-macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-proc-macro) is better for me.

Another thing is that you proposed the word `macro` without an `s`. I think we should stick to one style.

I don't think [macro-by-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macro-by-example) should be used to refer to common macros. As you said, this is used in the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html) but this documentation is not very used. I also don't know if they named it this way long ago and changed their mind — in the most recent book they call them [declarative macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html):

> the most widely used form of macros in Rust are declarative macros. These are also sometimes referred to as “macros by example”, “macro_rules! macros”, or just plain “macros”.

Declarative macro is in my opinion a better name that "macro-by-example".

I think we should either keep [rust-macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-macro) or change it to [rust-decl-macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-decl-macro) or [rust-declarative-macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-declarative-macro) (a long tag is not a big problem with auto-completion, but this feature is not always present)

---

To sum up my will:

- we remove [rust-macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-macros) because we will use two tag instead.
- we add [rust-decl-macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-decl-macro) for question that use them
- we add [rust-proc-macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-proc-macro) for question that use them
- we remove [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) from rust question
- we edit [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) to explain that all languages have different macros, and we add link to already existing tag their could be ambigus, [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba), [c-preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-preprocessor), [rust-decl-macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-decl-macro), [rust-proc-macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-proc-macro). (I think we will let other tag add their own tag and clean up things).

Comment: "by-example" is the declarative, pattern-matching style macro. i.e. the _other_ kind of macro,

Comment: The terminology is used for example here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html

Comment: *I think [tag:rust-macros] makes sense* — would you recommend *removing* [tag:macros] as well?

Comment: @Shepmaster I think this tag allow to regroup the macro concept in one tag. We can't edit tag info of [tag:macros] to include all possible languages macros definition, but we could edit it explain the situation and add link to specific tag for every language like their did for [tag:excel-vba]. We can't clean every question of SO, but we could take care of rust one and maybe other language will follow. Also, I think that doesn't hurt a question to have both [tag:rust-proc-macro] and [tag:macros]. Some people like to answer every macro question in any language.

Comment: @Shepmaster for [tag:rust-macros], I think if we add both [tag:rust-proc-macro] and [tag:rust-decl-macro] we should remove it. Because that would be too much tag to keep. [tag:macros] will just contain two link for rust case, where we have two type of macros, not a big deal.

Comment: Is this level of granularity really useful? If people are already using the more general [tag:macros] instead of [tag:rust-macros] I doubt they'd jump to two *more specific* tags which are even less discoverable in the tag editor. It seems like a bunch of ongoing retagging maintenance for very little gain. Do you expect many experts would follow a specific type of rust macro tag while ignoring the other?

Comment: @PaulCrovella I agree, I also doubt this would be very useful. I just thought it could be "clean" this way, we could remove it from questions and keep it on SO as a hub tag, "if you want use macros tag in your question don't use this one but prefer one of the more specific tag listed here". Is tag get deleted if they have too few questions ?

Comment: I *think* a tag gets deleted if it has no questions, but even if it didn't it wouldn't matter much - people out there asking don't read tag wiki info box usage guidance in the first place. If y'all'll make good use of the wiki space I can see favoring [tag:rust-macros] over [tag:macros], but there's plenty room there for both kinds of rust macros on the page. I don't see the practical value in them being divvied up, it seems more like just a taxonomic exercise.

Comment: @PaulCrovella "taxonomic exercise", exactly the purpose of tag ? I totally disagree, this is really useful to have both tag for rust.

Comment: Taxonomy isn't itself a purpose, it's a means to an end. I don't see what that end is here. What benefit is adding these tags bringing?

Comment: @PaulCrovella Simply sort questions, that would allow to search question and answer faster, especially because these questions will share the same keyword, but will be totally different. For example, if you want create a macro, declarative and procedural way are totally different but keyword would be "create" "macro". That for sure need two tags.

Comment: So this is for the benefit of people who are searching for "rust decl macro"?

Comment: @PaulCrovella Part of the reason is because prodedural macros have recently become more powerful in stable rust. There aren't many questions about them up until now because they haven't been used much, but there are likely to be a lot more coming.

Comment: TBH I'm leaning towards a single [tag:rust-macros] tag. It just seems like less maintenance.

Comment: @PeterHall I'm volunteer to take care of the work. I don't think it would take me a lot of time, of course after we will handle new question with proper tag but if you are afraid of the initial work I will do it.